# using click() function to open a link but keeping focus of the current window

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of links on the page and I'm using the javascript function "click()" to open all the links at once, but I don't want the focus to move to the new tab :

for example, I'll use this code :

```
document.getElementById("link1").click();
```

but I also want to keep the focus of current tab.

Comment: Sounds rather spammy. Hmmm...

Comment: Like the pop-under windows of old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate `CTRL + Click`

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", openBackgroundTab, false);

function openBackgroundTab() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = this.getAttribute("href");
  
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
  a.dispatchEvent(evt);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a id="test" href="http://www.google.com/">Open Google</a>
```

Comment: clicked on "Open Google" it switched to the new tab (focus) in chrome.

Comment: For me nothing happens at all

Comment: @Anthony, Which browser are you using? I have tested in now on chrome it works fine